# Breaking down list of records into their counts in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have two categories(`A` and `B`) with the following possible options:

```py
As = ['A1', 'A2']
Bs = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']
```

Assume the following input data in the form of a list of dictionaries:

```py
input_data = [
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B2'},
    {'A': 'A2', 'B': 'B3'},
    {'A': 'A2', 'B': 'B2'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B2'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'}
]
```

I want to break above into the counts of each constituent in the following format:

```py
expected_output = {
    'A': {
        'A1': {'B1': 5, 'B2': 2, 'B3': 0},
        'A2': {'B1': 0, 'B2': 1, 'B3': 1}
    },
    'B': {
        'B1': {'A1': 5, 'A2': 0},
        'B2': {'A1': 2, 'A2': 1},
        'B3': {'A1': 0, 'A2': 1}
    }
}
```

What is the best method in order to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from pprint import pprint

input_data = [
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B2'},
    {'A': 'A2', 'B': 'B3'},
    {'A': 'A2', 'B': 'B2'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B2'},
    {'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'}
]

d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(Counter))

mapping = {'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'}

for data in input_data:
    for k, v in data.items():
        reverse_key = data[mapping[k]]
        d[k][v][reverse_key] += 1

pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000021CB4665160>,
            {'A': defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
                              {'A1': Counter({'B1': 5, 'B2': 2}),
                               'A2': Counter({'B3': 1, 'B2': 1})}),
             'B': defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
                              {'B1': Counter({'A1': 5}),
                               'B2': Counter({'A1': 2, 'A2': 1}),
                               'B3': Counter({'A2': 1})})})
```

You could also use a nested `defaultdict` as well without `Counter`:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int)))
```

Which will give pretty much the same thing:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001D544AD5160>,
            {'A': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001D546AB89D0>,
                              {'A1': defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
                                                 {'B1': 5,
                                                  'B2': 2}),
                               'A2': defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
                                                 {'B2': 1,
                                                  'B3': 1})}),
             'B': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001D546AB8A60>,
                              {'B1': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A1': 5}),
                               'B2': defaultdict(<class 'int'>,
                                                 {'A1': 2,
                                                  'A2': 1}),
                               'B3': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'A2': 1})})})
```

**Note:** The above doesn't include `0` values. This doesn't matter because even if you do `d['A']['A1']['B3']`, you will get `0`.

Also `defaultdict` and `Counter` are subclasses of `dict`, so they can be treated as normal dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with the following solution:

```py
import itertools

grouping_func = lambda x: (x['A'], x['B'])
sorted_data = sorted(input_data, key=grouping_func)
groups = itertools.groupby(sorted_data, grouping_func)

A_results = {a: {b: 0 for b in Bs} for a in As}
B_results = {b: {a: 0 for a in As} for b in Bs}

for group, group_data in groups:
    a, b = group
    count = len(list(group_data))
    A_results[a][b] = count
    B_results[b][a] = count
output = {'A': A_results, 'B': B_results}
print(output)
```

I'm wondering if there is a better and more optimized method in order to achieve this?

Comment: This should be part of the question, which shows no attempt, rather than an answer which just poses another question.